# Hide Div permanently when CF7 form is submitted successfuly until cache or cookies is cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookies, contact-form-7

I have this script which popup a div on 5, 10 15 seconds interval when you click the close button

```
var iteration = 0;
var times = [5,10,15]

var showPopUp = function(time) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        jQuery('.pop_timer_box').css('display','flex');
    }, time)
}

showPopUp(times[iteration]);

jQuery('body').on('click', '.cclose_pop', function() {
    jQuery('.pop_timer_box').hide();
    iteration +=1;
    if (iteration < <?=$interval_array_count?>) {
      showPopUp(times[iteration])
    }
});
```

Inside the div is a contact form 7, and the code below hides the div when the form is submitted

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if(event.detail.contactFormId == '10917') {
    jQuery('.pop_timer_box').hide();
    }
}, false );
```

My question is how to make it so that when I submit a form and its successful the popup form won't appear anymore unless cache or cookie or localstorage is cleared

Comment: I think it is not possible in client side. You can do it from server side by using node to store the the id in file or db.

Comment: you can try to set localStorage with key and value by localStorage.setItem('showpopup', 'yes'); then when form is submited successfuly update same value to  'no' and then in your function 1st check localStorage value

Comment: But if localStorage is cleared then it will again showing

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
 }

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
function showNewsletterPopUp(){
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
     $('.popup').fadeIn(300); 
    }

 });
 jQuery(function($) {
     $('.parallax').on('scroll', function() {
      if($(".parallax").scrollTop() > 100) {
       $('.popup').fadeIn(300); 
   }
     })
 });
 $('.pop_close').click(function(){
     $('.popup').addClass('hide_this');
    });   
}
function checkCookie() {
 
 //console.log('hgghhggh');
  var user = getCookie("popup-attribute");

  if(typeof user === "undefined" || user == null || user == ''){
   console.log('HERE');
      showNewsletterPopUp();
      setCookie("popup-attribute", 'enable', 7);
  }
}
checkCookie();
```